# hidden: true doesn't hide paragraph

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p style="hidden: true;" id="demo">Hello!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't `hidden: true;` hide the paragraph? I can see it on the web page

Comment: use `display:none;` or `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: @xmaster What is the property "hidden" used for? What are its features?

Comment: check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)

Comment: @xmaster in that link "hidden" is used as a value, not as a property

Comment: hidden isn't a property... only a value and in the link you can read everything about it

Comment: @xmaster so it's wrong to write "hidden: true"?

Comment: yes it is. It will simply do nothing

Comment: There is no CSS property called `hidden`. There is, though, a universal HTML `attribute` called `hidden`.

Comment: Feel free to delete your question. It is not useful for others

Comment: HTML attribute `<p hidden` CSS: `<p style="display:none"`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `visibility: hidden;` for your style or you can use the hidden attribute like this

```
<p hidden>Hello!</p>
```

Comment: What is "hidden: true" used for?

Comment: You don't use "hidden:true" since it is not a valid html/css property. Instead you use attribute like in the code i have answered or use visibility:hidden in your style

Comment: Perhaps he meant `<p hidden="true">`

Comment: @mplungjan <p hidden="true"> is not a valid css attribute. You use <p hidden>

Comment: Sure. However hidden="hidden" might work :) Like disabled="disabled"

Comment: No hidden is an attribute you can't use it like that. Futher reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes

Comment: "disabled" is something you use when the input type is "checkbox". A checkbox is more like a boolean value of true or false which is why disabled works. You cannot use the same attribute for a p tag which does not have any boolean value rather simply display sting characters

Answer (score 0):

> `hidden: true` is not a valid css attribute

use:

```
<p style="display: none;" id="demo">Hello!</p>
```

this means that the tag will not appear on the page and there will be no space allocated

or:

```
<p style="visibility: hidden;" id="demo">Hello!</p>
```

this means that the tag is not visible, but space is allocated for it.

Comment: hidden is a valid HTML attribute - but used as CSS will not work